# Woocommerce display product category thumbnail above product thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show category thumbnail above product thumbnail in shop page. I tried to use this code but it doesn't works.

Please help me I need to get this done. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
        /**
     * Display product category thumbnail.
     *
     * @param mixed $product_category Category term Id, term name or term slug.
     */
    <?php
$thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_bid', true );
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Display product category thumbnail.
 *
 */
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_product_category_thumbnail', 20);
function display_product_category_thumbnail()
{
    global $product;

    $productFirstCategory = reset(get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_cat'));

    $small_thumb_size = 'woocommerce_thumbnail';
    $dimensions = wc_get_image_size($small_thumb_size);

    if ($thumbnail_id = get_term_meta($productFirstCategory->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true)) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id, $small_thumb_size);

        if (is_array($image)) {
            $image = reset($image);
        }

        $image_srcset = function_exists('wp_get_attachment_image_srcset') ? wp_get_attachment_image_srcset($thumbnail_id, $small_thumb_size) : false;
        $image_sizes = function_exists('wp_get_attachment_image_sizes') ? wp_get_attachment_image_sizes($thumbnail_id, $small_thumb_size) : false;
    } else {
        $image = wc_placeholder_img_src();
        $image_srcset = false;
        $image_sizes = false;
    }

    if ($image) {
        
        $src_set = '';
        if ($image_srcset && $image_sizes) {
            $src_set = '" srcset="' . esc_attr($image_srcset) . '" sizes="' . esc_attr($image_sizes);
        }

        echo '<img src="' . esc_url($image) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($productFirstCategory->name) 
            . '" width="' . esc_attr($dimensions['width']) . '" height="' 
            . esc_attr($dimensions['height']) . $src_set . '" />';
    }
}
```

1. You have to use the hook `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` which hooks your function to execute before products title.
2. The global variable `$product` holds the current looped product object.
3. Fetch the current products id and pass it to the WP function `get_the_terms` to fetch all the terms related to this product as an array and retrieve only first term object using the PHP function `reset` and assign it to the variable `$productFirstCategory`
4. The WooCommerce function `wc_get_image_size` retrieve the dimension details as an array
5. The next `if-else block` is used to assign either that product category image else default image
6. The final `if condition` is used output the image before the title

[image: Product and category image]